# using msmtp to send mail via php in docker container does NOT work in all cases

Tags: docker, msmtp

I am having issue making msmtp work in all cases when using php mail function. This is used in a docker container that relay's it to another docker container. It works in some cases but fails in others. See the php code for examples of when it fails/works.

msmtp version 1.8.22
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

msmtprc config

```
host        postfix
remove_bcc_headers off
allow_from_override off (When OFF breaks both mail functions)
```

PHP CODE: I need both cases to work at once

```php
$to = "me@chrismuench.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$from = 'chris@phppointofsale.com';
$headers = "From: $from";

//1. Works with allow_overide_from on
//2. I get error when allow_overide_from off msmtp: account default from /usr/local/etc/msmtprc: envelope-from address is missing 

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);

//Never works in either case (The php library I use does this and I do NOT want to modify core). (same error message with on/off for allow_overide_from)

//Error msmtp: cannot use both --from and --read-envelope-from
mail($to, $subject, $txt, $headers, '-f '.$from);
```

Comment: I fixed both cases by adding a `from` address in msmtprc

Comment: Also needed to remove --read-envelope-from

Comment: I'm having this problem, if you still have access to it, could you share your Dockerfile solution?